# is there can delete message when click this reaction emoji DIscord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How to fix this ? i want to delete message when user click reaction X

````
client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.channel.id === emojiChannelID) {
    try {
      await message.react('✅');
      await message.react('✖');
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
});```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kian here,

This code should work for you,
if you would like I can go through and explain each line :)

Have a good day chief!

```js
async function emojiMessage(message, validReactions) {
            for (const reaction of validReactions) await message.react(reaction);
        const filter = (reaction, user) => validReactions.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && (!user.bot)

        return message
            .awaitReactions(filter, {
                max: 1,
                time: 42000
            })
            .then(collected => collected.first() && collected.first().emoji.name);
}

async function deleteMessage(message) {

    const emoji = await emojiMessage(message, ["✅", "❌"]);
    console.log(emoji)
        // if the emoji is a tick:
    if (emoji === "✅") {
        // delete their message
        console.log("tick")
        if (message.deletable == true) {
            console.log("can delete")
            console.log("attempting to delete")
            message.delete()
        }
        if (!message.deletable == false) {
            "cannot delete"
        }
    } else if (emoji === "❌") { // if the emoji is a cross
        /*
         *  do something else
         */
        return;
    }

}


client.on('message', message => {

    if (message.channel.id === emojiChannelID) {
        // runs the function
        deleteMessage(message)
    }
    /*
     * do something else
     */
})
```

#### Note:

First upload

I've tried my best to make the code understandable/work , if there is any issues feel free to comment, I'll fix it :)

Comment: const emoji = await emojiMessage(message, ["✅", "❌"]);
                  ^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function @Unkwn

Comment: I've edited the code, try again and see if it works now

Comment: the new problem is nothing happen

Comment: @HypexBot I've changed the code and tested it. Its working for me, If you are the server owner or above it in the role hierarchy it wont be able to delete your message. I've included some console.log's that can be used for testing. have a good one chief

Comment: How about if the bot can only access reaction by specific role or with permission

Answer (score 1):

There's an `message.awaitReaction()` in [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions), that will return reactions from users

```js
// Filter for only
const filter = function(reaction, user) { 
  return reaction.emoji.name === '✅' || reaction.emoji.name === '✖';
}

// {...}

let reactionMessage = await message.react('✅');
// Make sure to set max: 1 so that the promise returns after the first reaction
let reactionCollection = await reactionMessage.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1});
// reactionCollection is a Collection<string, MessageReaction>
// Use first() to get the first (and only)
let reaction = reactionCollection.first();
```

Comment: hmm identifier " message " has been declared

Comment: reactionMessage.awaitReactions is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Example Usage:

```
const m = await message.channel.send('hi!');
reactionDelete(m, message, 20000); // assuming 'message' is the actual sent message
```

```
async function reactionDelete (botMessage, playerMessage, timeout) {

    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return ['️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === playerMessage.author.id;
    };

    botMessage.react('️');

    botMessage.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: timeout})
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '️') {
            botMessage.delete();
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        if (botMessage.deletable) botMessage.reactions.removeAll();
    });

};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/27118439)